# The FFT of a top-hat function looks mirrored/flipped (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am applying `numpy.fft.fft` function to a simple 'top-hat' function, i.e. all values are 0 except over a given x-range where they are 1.
[image: E field versus x]

The problem arises when I apply a fast fourier transform to the data. It outputs what I am expecting, which is a Gaussian profile, but it looks like instead of being centred on 0 the peaks are at the edges. I am expecting the peak to be central. It's as if the output was split down the centre, and mirrored.
[image: FFT of E-field]

Is there a way of centering this output data other than manually flipping the output array? Why is it doing this?

Here's my full code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def find_nearest(array, value):
    """ Finds the nearest array value index for a particular value."""
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return idx

aperture_length = 81.92e-3 # in metres
start = - aperture_length / 2
end = aperture_length / 2
step = 0.02e-3

x = np.arange(start, end, step)
E = np.zeros(len(x))

slit_length = 1e-3
ind1 = find_nearest(x, -slit_length/2)
ind2 = find_nearest(x, slit_length/2)

for i in range(len(E)):
    if i <= ind2 and i >= ind1:
        E[i] = 1

# Compute FFT
trans = fft(E, norm='ortho')

fig = plt.figure(dpi=150)
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(x, E)
ax1.set_title(r'E vs. x')

plt.figure(dpi=150)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax2.plot(x, trans)
# ax2.set_xlim(-0.02, 0.02)
ax2.set_title(r'FFT of E')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Third paragraph of "Implementation Details" on [this page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html) seems to answer your question

Comment: The origin is in the first sample, both for input and output of your FFT. So you input function is a shifted top hat (it is 1 away from zero). This is what causes the wild swinging in the output. Note also that you are plotting only the real part of the FFT, and dropping the imaginary part.

Comment: The fft is periodic, meaning if you were to plot it or the discrete fourier transform for all n on the x axis, you would see the same profile over and over. The plot shown is what you will get for one period when finding the fft or the dft. It contains all the correct information, it is just not presented as you are used to seeing it. By applying np.fft.fftshift after you take the fft, you will arrange that information to be centered about zero.

Comment: Thank you all, `np.fft.fftshift` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.